# Will charges attract or repel?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

If the universe consist of only two particles namely electron and proton, and if they are separated away by huge distance, they will still attract each other.

- Can we prove it without using Coulomb's law?
- Can we find out why they attract or what causes them to attract?
- What really happens there that makes the both particles move towards each other?

Comment: Physics explains how, but doesn't answer why.

Comment: Yes I agree. So could you tell how actually does the process of attraction of 2 particles really works

Comment: Such a universe doesn't exist and physics is not about constructing minimal universe, either. You can have a proton and an electron in this universe, even in a tiny volume in a vacuum vessel in your lab and they will behave just as your imaginary infinite almost empty universe will. There is nothing wrong with working in reality and you shouldn't be afraid of it. Physics is the art of messy approximations of messy natural phenomena. As my first theory teacher said, if you can't handle that, the physics department is not for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Physics does not answer why questions, except with how from postulates and mathematical models one can describe the data. The how is Coulombs law.

Physics is about fitting experimental observations with mathematical models. The answer to the "why  attraction" in this case, is, data dictates so. There is no other answer except that Coulomb's law fits the data. Our present theories of physics incorporate this law in more inclusive mathematical models, *because* of this experimental fact.

Comment: So all we can do is just predict because the charges attract or repel on small scales so would they do on the large or very large cases?

Comment: @ParthMaske, yup, you've got it. If we can't do an experiment, we've got build the best theory we can from what we *can* measure and extrapolate  :-D

Comment: @ParthMaske: Predict? Not at all. What do you think LHC is? It's a machine to measure interaction of charges at the smallest distances we can afford to create. At the large end one can do measurements on light across the entire universe and it behaves just as expected. There is not a single measurement that violates what we have learned, so far, about the Coulomb interaction.