# How do electrons absorb and reflect photons 100% of the times if their existence is based on probabilities in the density cloud?

Tags: visible-light, photons, elementary-particles

Shouldnt there be observations where we never see the color of an object because none of their electrons existed in the space where photons would hit them ? Or does this not happen because of how many photos are traveling constantly ? and if we send a photon particle by particle(not even sure if we can), will we then have 50-50 chances to see the surface give color or nah? Coming from a comp sci major who's just curious about physics.

Comment: They don’t absorb or reflect 100% of the time

Comment: Oh.. so it is indeed a probability too ? But why don't we see such things in real life?

Comment: Photons go flying by atoms all the time without interacting much. Otherwise it would be really hard to see the sun.

Comment: of course we do see such things. look at our medical x-rays.  if x-ray photons reflected or interacted with matter 100% of the time, we wouldn't see anything past our skin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this answer of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421058/why-do-electrons-absorb-and-re-emit-photons/421084#421084) to a similar question, "Why do electrons absorb and re-emit photons?".

Also look at the continuous spectrum of electromagnetic radiation, of which a tiny part is the visual, colored rainbow spectrum, [the table on the right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Electromagnetic_spectrum).

> Shouldnt there be observations where we never see the color of an object because none of their electrons existed in the space where photons would hit them ?

We do not see radiation because of the photon scattering off an electron, we see the radiation emitted by photons interacting with the surface of the object at all levels, atomic, molecular, lattice. Objects have a dense spill over electric field at the surface, and photons can always scatter from it too,  the lattice level.

> Or does this not happen because of how many photos are traveling constantly ? and if we send a photon particle by particle(not even sure if we can), will we then have 50-50 chances to see the surface give color or nah?

There are zillions of photons in a beam of light. In addition [color perception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision) is a complicated higher level process in the retina of the eye. ([this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions) of mine talks about it)

If no photons are reflected towars our eye, we will see the color "black" for the object. We may also see "black" if most of the photons are absorbed by the atoms/molecules/ at the surface of the object, and too few arrive at our retina to register a color.