# Does an electron emit radiation the instant it absorbs it?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons

I was reading on the electromagnetic spectrum when I thought if an atom/electron is absorbing the energy from the light ray falling on it, how and by when will it get rid of the excess energy to become stable again. If it emitted the light radiation at the same instant, wouldn't it interfere with the emission spectrum band?

Comment: Does anything happen instantaneously (in zero time)?

Comment: [A related answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/421084/44126).